# create star triangle with php

Tags: php

I want to make a triangle like this with php , but i try in local still fail how to code like the example above

```
<?php
    $star=10;
    for($a=1; $a<=$star; $a++){
    for($c=$star; $c>=$a; $c-=1){
        echo "*";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

I have value  1225441. How to create output like this with looping php?

```
1000000
200000
20000
5000
400
40
1
```

Comment: Your sample output doesn't seem to have any stars in it, so I don't understand how it relates to the title, or the example code.

Comment: how to create ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea with a for loop.
You just need to know how long your input is, and pad the output with the length of your input, gradually getting smaller with each iteration.

```
<?php
# Replace this with whatever is the source of your input.
$input = '1225441';

# get total number of characters in input
$length = strlen($input);
# foreach character in input
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    # echo the character as many times as $length - $i - 1.
    echo $input[$i] . str_repeat(0, $length - $i - 1) . '<br>';
}
```

This creates the output of:

```
1000000
200000
20000
5000
400
40
1
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's hard for you to think about how to do it with PHP, then think first about the general way to do it, I mean the algorithm. You can represent it with a flow diagram. Then, you just need to *translate* it to PHP code.

And the result it can be something like this:

```
<?php

$n = 1225441;

$string = '' . $n; //Let`s have a string for better use string functions

for ($c = 0, $len = strlen($string); $c < $len; $c++) {
    echo substr($string, $c, 1);
    for ($k = $len - 1; $k > $c; $k--) {
        echo '0';
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution as a one-liner.

```
$n = '1225441';
array_reduce(str_split($n),fn($c,$i)=>$c-(print $i.str_repeat('0',$c)."\n"),strlen($n)-1);
```

#### Output

```
1000000
200000
20000
5000
400
40
1
```